# [Magento][2.4.3] Deduct source item on refund

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, msi, msi-source

I have config MSI for my store and I have some problem.
When I call api /V1/invoice/:invoiceId/refund to refund my order with payment type is online payment (ex: paypal, ATM..) after refund success, on Product grid, column "Sale quantity" be refund stock (it's right) but column "Quantity per source" be deducted, I have check and detect we has event "deduct_source_item_quantity_on_refund" and I do not understand what logic for this event and how can I keep "Quantity per source" by config ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For now its better to disable the plugin, afaik, there is no point of decucting the source Qty on creating a credit memo.

The source qty should be ideally remaining the same and if shipment is not created the reservations should be compensated / released.